# Android: How to draw line with rounded corner?

Tags: android, android-canvas

How can I draw line/arc with rounded corners as you can see on the picture below?
I need to draw this on `Canvas`.

[image]

Comment: Did you take a look at  `Paint.Cap.ROUND` ?

Comment: yes but cap.round make one big circle at the end I need two rounded corners

Answer (score 8):

I think you can workaround this by drawing three lines with a partial overlap:

- two external lines with `Paint.Cap.ROUND`
- one inner line with `Paint.Cap.BUTT`

Assuming your input data is

```
float lineWidth = 20;
float lineRadius = 100;
float cornerRadius = 2;
```

You go as follows,

```
float width, radius;
// Draw outer lines
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
width = cornerRadius * 2;

// Draw inner
radius = lineRadius - lineWidth/2f + cornerRadius;
canvas.draw(...)

// Draw outer
radius = lineRadius + lineWidth/2f - cornerRadius;
canvas.draw(...)

// Draw center
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
width = lineWidth - 2f*cornerRadius;
radius = lineRadius;
canvas.draw(...)
```

You might need to slightly alter the arc angle for the center line (it must be `cornerRadius` longer, on each side) but that is easy.

Comment: In this example `width` is basically the stroke width, and `radius` is the distance from the circle center to the middle of each line. I don’t know what `Canvas` takes as input, but this should be easy to modify.

Comment: what is the value for canvas.draw(...)